# How can I bring input field texts to address bar?

Tags: javascript, html, url, input-field, address-bar

If I type some texts in the input field, how can I bring those texts to address bar ?

for eg : I type **abcd** to input field, I need address bar like **[www.google.com/abcd](http://www.google.com/abcd)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function updateAddressBar() {
  const inputValue = document.getElementById("inputField").value;
  window.history.replaceState({}, '', `?value=${inputValue}`);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="inputField" oninput="updateAddressBar()">
</form>
```

The **oninput** event is used to call the **updateAddressBar** function whenever the value of the input field changes. The function uses document.getElementById to get the value from the input field, and then window.history.replaceState to update the URL with the new value from the input field.

Answer (score 0):

This can work:

```html
<body>
<p>Typing something...</p>

<input type="text" id="Input1" onkeyup="displayResult()"><!--onkeypress can not function backspace-->
  <br>
<button id="Hite">
  Hite
  </button>
<script>
function displayResult()
{
  var text = "www.google.com";
  
  var Input1Value = document.getElementById("Input1").value;
  
  document.getElementById("Hite").innerHTML = text +"\\"+ Input1Value + "\\";

  
  
}
</script>
```

I using *onkeyup* event so when the value of the input changes, it will function to set the text. Also, the reason why I do not using *onkeypress* is: *onkeypress* can not function when you press *backspace*.

Then, if you want to get the address, you can use *document.getElementById("Hite").innerHTML* to get it (As you did not required to get it)